# WP users cant reset password

Tags: users, login, password

I had users complains that they forgot their password,
and after they changed and being accepted, when they try to login they get pass error.
I tested it and i confirmed that the changed pass is not working
https://prnt.sc/lyrkzx
Any ideas ?

Comment: hi  please check your user name

Comment: Alll members forgot their usernames ?
Anyway i tested it myself and is not working.

Comment: debug on in wp-config.php file and check error

Comment: you use cache plugin?

Comment: add this wp-config and check error  define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );